# Where to get the latest version of cordova.js for iPhone

Tags: cordova

I don't understand why there isn't a cdn for all the different cordova.js files.

I am trying to come up with the most straightforward example of including cordova.js for iPhone without resorting to the phoneGap build process, which strikes me as making things complicated so that they can be simple.

Can I do something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/cordova/ios/latest/cordova.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you using to build/compile your applications?

Comment: Dreamweaver to build, and then I'm ftping it to a server.

Comment: I was hoping to have my "application" be an html5 web page.

Comment: so you aren't using the phonegap build service or the cordova command line tool? cordova.js wont run from a web browser, it needs to run locally on a device.

Comment: Ohhhh... cordova.js wont run from a web browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not work.

I don't think. that the user really would like websites, which could read all local files an you adressbook.

Cordova is made creating a *native* application with a html5 webview and javascript as language.

You will have to use the commandline toolchain or the web-build service.

```
npm install cordova -g
```